# How to read hard disk utilization and stats using node.js or electronjs for windows and mac

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, macos, electron

I'm wondering how could I read hard disk utilization / idle time, hdd type using Javascript for Windows and MacOS. I have access to nodejs and electron API for my app. I can't seem to find any API or npm packages that allow reading of harddisk stats and disk utilization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is 1 npm package "systeminformation" which provides these details :
Below is the reference : https://www.npmjs.com/package/systeminformation

```js
const si = require('systeminformation');


setInterval(function() {
    si.mem(function(data) {
        console.log('Memory-Information:');
        console.log(data);
    });
}, 1000)
```